# My question is about the domain of an inverse trigonometric function

Tags: functions

What is the domain of : 
$$\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac {1-x^2}x} \right)$$
this is what i did
f(x)=frac {1-x^2}x≥0 ⇔ 1-x^2 ≥ 0 ⇔ (1-x)*(1+x) ≥ 0 ⇔ x ∈ [-1,1 ] so the domain of f(x) is [-1,1 ] 
how can i prove that  -1 ≤sqrt{\frac {1-x^2}x≤ 1 ?

Comment: It is (almost...) impossible to understand the expression in the argument of arcsine.

Comment: Is that correct $\arcsin\left(\sqrt[2]{\frac {1-x^2}x} \right)$?

Comment: it's my first time here and i'm not good at writing with Mathjax , what's inside is sqrt (frac : 1-x¨2 / x)

Comment: @kennybunny If you edit the question (or using right button) you can see how you can write that. Refer also to [MATHJAX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: First, you can read the instructions before signing up. Second, even if you don't use MATHJAX, you can always use parenthesis: sqrt((1-x^2)/x) or something like that, to make clear what you mean.

Comment: @gimusi thank you !

Comment: @DonAntonio it's clear now

Comment: @kennybunny You are welcome! Try to solve following the given hint and show your work here. I'll take a look to that if you need some more check.

Comment: @kennybunny Add and show your work here editing your question, otherwise the question could be closed for lacking of context.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

For a function $\arcsin (\sqrt{f(x)})$ we need

- $f(x)\ge 0$ for the definition of $\sqrt{f(x)}$
- $-1\le \sqrt{f(x)}\le 1\implies 0\le \sqrt{f(x)}\le 1$ for the definition of $\arcsin$

Comment: Thank you , i used the first hint but i couldn't figure out what to do next

Comment: @kennybunny That's nice please show in your original question what you have obtained from that. I'll check your work in order to give some other suggestions.

Comment: $f(x) =frac{1-x^2}{x}$≥0 ⇔ 1-x^2 ≥ 0 ⇔ (1-x)*(1+x) ≥ 0 ⇔ x ∈ [-1,1 ] so the domain of  f(x) is  [-1,1 ]

Comment: Add that directly in your question, I will take a look to that.

Comment: We  have $1-x^2\ge0$ and $x>0$ or $1-x^2\le0$ and $x<0$.

Answer (score 0):

We need to have $x\ne 0$ and

- $\dfrac{1-x^2}x\ge 0\iff x(1-x^2)\ge 0\iff x\in(-\infty, -1]\cup (0,1]$.
- $\dfrac{1-x^2}x\ge 1\iff\begin{cases}1-x^2\le x,\;\text{ i.e. }\; x^2+x-1\ge 0 &\text{if }x>0,\\
  1-x^2\ge x,\;\text{ i.e. }\; x^2+x-1\le 0 &\text{if }x<0.\end{cases}$

Now the quadratic polynomial $\:p(x)=x^2+x-1\:$ has one negative root and one positive root:
$$\xi_1=\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}2,\qquad\xi_2=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}2.$$
Furthermore, as $p(-1)<0,\; p(1)>0$, we know that
$$\xi_1<-1<\xi_2<1.$$
Can you conclude from all these particulars?